# Calculate the volume of objects in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, regions, geometry, trigonometry

Is there a way to calculate the volume of these different regions without making the algebra ?

```
{{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
  ClipPlanes -> {InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, -0.0664608}, {0, 
       1, -0.0664608}, {1, 1, -0.0664608}}]}, Opacity[0.5], 
  Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.986202]}, {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
  ClipPlanes -> {InfinitePlane[{{0, 1, -0.0664608}, {0, 
       0, -0.0664608}, {1, 1, -0.0664608}}]}, Opacity[0.5], 
  Sphere[{0, 0, 0.831202}, 1.33191]}, {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
  ClipPlanes -> {InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, -0.0664608}, {0, 
       1, -0.0664608}, {1, 1, -0.0664608}}]}, Opacity[0.5], 
  Sphere[{0, 0, 0.677365}, 1.23347]}}
```

I'm using this in a `Graphics3D`.

More generally, I'd like to enter into `Graphics3D` what I want and to get the volume without entering into complicated trigonometry. I tried to use `Volume[]` but I did not manage to go from this description of the region to something that fits `Volume[]`

Answer (score 1):

Graphics primitives you use in `Graphics3D` also work with [regions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricComputation.html) - read about those in docs, there many helpful functions. For example, your case something as simple as this works:

```
Volume[RegionUnion[
    Ball[{0,0,0},0.986202],
    Ball[{0,0,0.831202},1.33191],
    Ball[{0,0,0.677365},1.23347]
]]
```

> 11.0001

and no need for `ClipPlanes` because `ClipPlanes` takes care not counting duplicate volume. Note, `Sphere` does not have a volume, it is a shell, so use `Ball`.

But I see you got actually one region inside 2 others. So, did you mean to cut out that one? In this case, you could do something like this (note, just for the fun of it I am sowing symbolic power of regions):

```
symReg=Rationalize[{
Ball[{0,0,0},0.986202],
Ball[{0,0,0.831202},1.33191],
Ball[{0,0,0.677365},1.23347]}]

Out[]=  
{Ball[{0,0,0},493101/500000], 
Ball[{0,0,415601/500000},133191/100000],
Ball[{0,0,135473/200000},123347/100000]}

Volume[RegionUnion[symReg[[;;2]]]]-Volume[RegionUnion[symReg[[3]]]]
```

$$\frac{207637012757096261485097 \pi }{207800500000000000000000}$$